# How do I add sliders to the Mac menu bar?

Tags: macos, kotlin, swing, menu, menubar

I'm using Swing with Kotlin to make a Tetris clone, and I want to use JSliders in the menu bar to control some settings (in this case, how rounded the edges of the pieces' squares are, and the size of the gap between them).

The sliders show up and work as intended when I keep the menu bar in the main frame, but I don't want it there; I want to use the native macOS menu bar at the top of the screen.

The problem is that when I try to add sliders to the macOS menu bar, neither the JSliders nor their associated JLabels show up in it, even though everything else does just fine.

This is how it looks on Windows: [image: sliders visible in windows menu bar]

This is how it looks on mac:
[image: sliders not visible in mac menu bar]

I'd like the slider in the mac menu bar to look like this playback slider from vlc:
[image: playback speed slider in mac menu bar]

This is the code I'm using to add the sliders to my menu on both platforms. It produces the results shown above.

This creates a visual preferences menu

```
fun createVisualPrefsMenu(): JMenu {
    /* omitted some other menu items for clarity */
    val menu = JMenu("Visual Preferences")
    val gapLabel = JLabel("Gap: " + Theme.gap)
    val gapSlider = JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 42, Theme.gap)
    gapSlider.addChangeListener {
        Theme.gap = gapSlider.value // doesn't show up on the menu for some reason
        gapLabel.text = "Gap: " + Theme.gap
    }

    val bevelLabel = JLabel("Roundness: " + Theme.bevelPercent)
    val bevelSlider = JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, 0, 100, (Theme.bevelPercent * 100).toInt())
    bevelSlider.addChangeListener {
        Theme.bevelPercent = bevelSlider.value.toFloat() / 100 // doesn't show up on the menu for     some reason
        bevelLabel.text = "Roundness: " + Theme.bevelPercent
    }

    menu.add(bevelLabel)
    menu.add(bevelSlider)
    menu.add(gapLabel)
    menu.add(gapSlider)
    return menu
}
```

Which is added to the JMenuBar that this method creates

```
private fun createTableMenuBar(): JMenuBar {
    val menuBar = JMenuBar()
    /* omitted some other additions to the menuBar for clarity */
    menuBar.add(createVisualPrefsMenu())
    menuBar.validate()
    return menuBar
}
```

That JMenuBar is then set as the frame's overall JMenuBar

```
init {
    /* stuff */
    menuBar = createTableMenuBar() // menuBar is a field
    frame.jMenuBar = menuBar
    /* other stuff */
}
```

This code is called before anything else in my main method. This sets the JMenu and only if the operating system is detected to be macOS.

```
fun main() {
    if (SystemInfo.isMacOS) {
        /* stuff */
        System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", Theme.hasTransparentWindowBar.toString())
        // hasTransparentWindowBar is true for this demonstration
        /* stuff */
    }

    val g = GraphicsPanel
    g.run()
}
```